# How set transparent top navbar on Zurb foundation framework?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How can I put transparent top navbar ? I set background transparent with css but not work

Comment: Please provide us the code

Comment: do you have a codepen or something with the code?, not sure if "top navbar" refers to the "top bar" component or something else

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the top bar in your page using your browsers dev tool inspector, you'll see the background colour is applied to two parts of the navbar. You can make the background transparent by specifying the following CSS:

```
.top-bar, .top-bar ul {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```